# What is Device Encryption feature?

Tags: windows-8

Reference to [Wikipedia-Win8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions)

What is this device encryption feature? What am I missing by choosing Pro or RT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Device encryption refers to the ability to protect local device data from offline hardware attacks by employing encryption. This is achieved by employing a file-based encryption filter. The master key for the encryption is protected with the user’s device lock PIN.

When device encryption is enabled, during bootup the user is prompted to enter the PIN. Until the PIN is entered, bootup is suspended.

useful link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964600.aspx

In windows RT you get the device encryption which is definately a plus if you have some private data.

Comment: Just to expand on why this is a good thing - without it, a thief who gets your phone may also get access to all your data, online accounts, emails, social media etc. With encryption, the effort required is likely to mean an attacker will not get that information. **Use Device Encryption**